# Which license is »MQTT for Tcl« released under?

Tags: tcl, mqtt, licensing

Which license is [MQTT for Tcl](http://chiselapp.com/user/schelte/repository/mqtt/home) released under?

I can't find contact information of the author Schelte Bron, and the sources don't state the license - but he has an account here, so I ask here :)

Comment: Hi @Schelte Bron can you answer this question?

Comment: It appears to be formally unlicensed. The [author](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7994192/schelte-bron) will need to be contacted directly, alas…

Comment: @DonalFellows Yes one would have to do that, but I didn't find contact information, as I stated in my initial question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no problem to release the code under the BSD 3-clause revised license. I have just added that license to the project.